# Тестировние с Mockito объясните на пальцах

Tags: java, исключения, junit, mockito

Проверяю метод

```
public Message findOne(Long id) {
    Message message = messageRepository.findOne(id);
    if (message == null) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    return message;
}
```

тест вариант 1, проходит даже если в проверяемом методе заменить DataNotFoundException на NullPointerException. Не должен вроде?

```
@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)
public void findOneIsNullThenException1() {
    when(messageServiceImp.findOne(2L)).thenThrow(DataNotFoundException.class);
    Message testMessage = messageServiceImp.findOne(2L);
}
```

Тест вариант 2, не проходит ни как

```
@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)
public void findOneIsNullThenException() {
    //prepare
    when(messageServiceImp.findOne(2L));
    then(caughtException())
            .isInstanceOf(DataNotFoundException.class)
            .hasMessageContaining("Data with id=2 not found.");
// А так же пробовал с
    thenThrown(DataNotFoundException.class);
}
```

получаю ошибку

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.sttech.springrest.exception.DataNotFoundException> but was<java.lang.AssertionError>
....
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual not to be null
....
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Дополнение:

Я что то перестал понимать как вообще тестировать с помощью mockito. У меня есть класс MessageServiceImp в нем есть методы которые я хочу протестировать.
Буду отталкиваться все от того же метода что выше, но протестировать его не только на исключения.

В классе MessageServiceImp есть зависимость MessageRepository которую надо проинжектировать, по этому отмечаем ее как мок и инжектируем в класс.

```
@Mock
private MessageRepository messageRepository;
@InjectMocks
MessageServiceImp messageServiceImp;
```

Далее сам тест.

```
@Test
public void findOne() throws Exception {
    //prepare
    when(messageRepository.findOne(ID)).thenReturn(MESSAGE);
    //testing
    Message testMessage = messageServiceImp.findOne(ID);
    //validate
    verify(messageRepository).findOne(ID);
}
```

В таком виде тест проходит, смотрим, а что он там вообще тестирует? вроде как должен вызов метода `findOne` и вернуть должен объект `MESSAGE` (по сути мне бы подошел и возврат любого объекта `anyObject()`). 
Проверяем, меняем в проверяемом методе возвращаемое значение на `null` и ... тест все равно проходит. Я ведь объект ожидаю, а получаю `null` и тест проходит.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вам надо мокать messageRepository, а не messageServiceImp.

Comment: @Vartlok Попробовал я с messageRepository и все стало еще более запутанно. Добавил выше.

Comment: А вы пробовали дебажить? Проверьте, что происходит внутри messageServiceImp.findOne, почему там нулл возвращается, а не эксепшен. С виду у вас теперь всё норм.

Comment: @Vartlok Да там вроде все нормально, он обращается к messageRepository получает или объект или если не найден null (в таком случае кидает исключение). Мне не понятно почему если вместо return message; я возвращаю return null; тест проходит, он же ожидает получить объект а не null.

Comment: Прошелся еще раз внимательно дебагером. Я правильно понимаю, что мой тест проверяет что вернет messageRepository в строке when ... thenReturn? Если так, то да возращается объект. Но я хочу проверить что возращает  MessageServiceImp.findOne() я же вроде как этот метод тестирую.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void findOne() throws Exception {
    // prepare
    when(messageRepository.findOne(ID)).thenReturn(MESSAGE);
    // testing
    Message testMessage = messageServiceImp.findOne(ID);
    // validate
    verify(messageRepository).findOne(ID);
    assertEquals(MESSAGE, messageServiceImp.findOne(ID));
}
```

Конструкция when.thenReturn и последующая verify проверяет, что сработал вызов мока, в данном случае

```
Message message = messageRepository.findOne(id);
```

И возвращает объект а не что то иное.
И дополнительная проверка assertEquals уже проверяет возвращаемое значение самого метода MessageServiceImp.findOne()